# нужна помощь как реализовать регистрацию

Tags: android, json, post, get

есть edittext и button 
в edittext (номер телефона), button (регистрация)
как реализовать регистрацию ? есть API /сервера 
(как ватсапе водим номер телефона приходит код активации) 
или у кого есть готовый код?

код Main.java

```
EditText editTextPhone;
Button buttonRegister;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
    this.editTextPhone.setText("996");
         editTextPhone.setSelection(3);

    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.v("EditText", editTextPhone.getText().toString());
            //Log.v("EditText value=", editTextPhone.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
}
```

тут нашел этот код !

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
private EditText login , pass;
private Button mSubmit, mRegister;


private static String Data;

public static void NmSN(String data){
    Data = data;
}
// Progress Dialog

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// php login script location:

// localhost :
// testing on your device
// put your local ip instead, on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
// or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
// private static final String LOGIN_URL =
// "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

// testing on Emulator:
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://nw.pe.hu/******.php";

// testing from a real server:
// private static final String LOGIN_URL =
// "http://www.mybringback.com/webservice/login.php";

// JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "ifAuth";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // setup input fields
    login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    // setup buttons
    mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    // register listeners
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubs
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = login.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save login data

                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("username", username);
                edit.commit();
                new AttemptGetData().execute(json.getString("ID"));
                JSONObject jsone = new JSONObject(Data);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileAct.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", json.getString("ID"));
                i.putExtra("name", jsone.getString("name"));
                i.putExtra("surname", jsone.getString("surname"));
                i.putExtra("avatar", jsone.getString("avatar"));
                finish();
                startActivity(i);



                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Неверный логин и\"или пароль!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

}
```

могу ли я собрать из этого кода json ( post get )